# Ubuntu Server install via USB. No Install option, only Test Memory and Rescue

Tags: installation, server, usb, 13.10

I have created a USB Install drive based on ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso using Universal USB Installer v1.9.4.8. 
When I boot from the USB drive after selecting my language, I do not get the option to Install Ubuntu Server.  I only get the following options:

- Test Memory
- Boot from first hard disk
- Rescue a broken system

If I burn the iso to a CD and boot via an external USB CD drive the following menu options are available:

- Install Ubuntu Server
- Multiple server Install with MAAAS
- Check disk for defects
- Test Memory
- Boot from first hard disk
- Rescue a broken system

Is this a problem with the Ubuntu Server .iso file or with Universal USB Installer?

My motherboard is an ASROCK Z87 Extreme6 in case it's an issue with my chipset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just experienced the same exact issue.  I also used ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso and Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.4.8.exe.  I'm using a 1GB flash drive that also worked fine with the ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso installer.

Turns out UUI 1.9.4.9 was released on 20-Nov-2013, with "Fix broken Ubuntu Server options." in the changelog, so that answers your question of where the problem lies.  I just downloaded [Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.0.exe](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.0.exe) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, it's the flash drive, and certainly not the motherboard. If you get so far along as to reach the GRUB2 screen to show you choices, then the motherboard is capable of booting from a USB FlashDrive and configured to permit same. Therefore, I'd reformat the flashdrive before retrying. - and how big is that flashdrive?

Comment: The flash drive is 16GB.  In Universal USB Installer v1.9.4.8 I checked the box to format the device.  There is no problem if I use the 13.10 Desktop installer from the same flash drive so I wouldn't think it's the issue.